# Long division answer differs to calculator answer

Tags: divisibility

Can someone make sure I'm not going mad, I'm doing very simple long division: $271÷15$.

I work it out as $18.06\bar 3$ but a calculator returns $18.0\bar 6$?

What's going on here? Do I  have a mental block or something?

Comment: Both are wrong.  It will be $18.0\overline{6}$.

Comment: Well, it may be a classic case of the silly mistake called "calculation error". To pinpoint it, it would be helpful if you posted photo of your long division. P.S. pardon the unfunny sarcasm.

Comment: Probably an error in your long division, and an error in what you plugged into, or read from, the calculator, or typed into your question.

Comment: @JMoravitz OP may have missed a zero. Probably the silly mistake called "typing error".

Comment: Sorry, I did mean 18.0666r on calculator, not sure I know how to post a pic tho lol

Comment: $\dfrac{271}{15} = 18+\dfrac{1}{15}\,$ and $\,\dfrac{1}{15}= \dfrac{1}{10}\dfrac{10}{15} = \dfrac{1}{10}\dfrac{2}{3}= 10^{-1}\ 0.\overline{6} = 0.0\overline{6}\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron Wilden see the image I have attached below.

[image]

Comment: Nice job.......

Comment: @amWhy This is the exact manner in which long division is introduced to 3rd/4th graders in India. So I guess, your comment should be directed to our textbooks :)

Comment: Indeed, also in the U.S. +1